# ruby 2.5.3 version installed, but ruby -v still showing 2.3.7 version

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I've installed version 2.5.3 successfully, but ruby -v still show 2.3.7 version.

rbenv 2.5.3
rbenv global 2.5.3
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

Comment: Run [`rbenv rehash`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-rehash).

Comment: it works. problem solved! Thanks